# how to Listern to peer chat collection and update user collection

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i am creating application and i am peering two user id together to create the Chat collection. i am now try to update time stamp of user so that the last person i chat with will be the first the list...

also with listen to unread message

**please i just need idea on how to create it**

example of what i want to create.
[image]